# Change the color of text within a hovered li by css

Tags: css

I am wondering if it is possible to update the color of a text within a li-block if that li-block gets hovered.

So, like that situation

```
<li><h3>Foo</h3><p>Supertext</p></li>
```

and I have

```
li:hover{
background:red;
}
```

and I would also want to be capable of doing

```
li:hover{
background:red;
color:green !important; //But that doesn't work
}
```

Any chance of doing this by css?
[JSBIN.](http://jsbin.com/zevumutebe/1/edit)

Comment: may the elements from inside have some other color that overrides the hover from the li, the it should be `li:hover element { color: green; }`

Comment: `li:hover > *{ color: green !important;}`

Comment: Whoaha....why the !important here? Just be more specific...

Comment: You must have other CSS rules for the content of your `li`. This works fine  > http://jsfiddle.net/uresdg3b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
li:hover p  {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
li:hover h3  {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

(Change the colors accordingly of course)

OR you can add hover to the list-item instead like this:

```
li p:hover   {
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
}
li h3:hover   {
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
}
```

You can also wrap elements within the list-items in a span and add a common span style for both.

Comment: Though I would recommend wrapping the list-item element inside an anchor and using li a:hover {....} instead.